# Click on a layout cause all textview changing color

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to set a background to a textview when i click on them. But when i click on the global layout, all textviews change background.

layout file that i use as an item in a listview, and when i click on a item in this list, all textviews change color (to green).

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    android:padding="6dip" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/lines" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ll_main">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
        android:id="@+id/ll_content">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/VotePlus"
            android:text="Plus" 
            android:id="@+id/tv_vote_plus"
            android:background="@drawable/change_tv_bg"/>
        <TextView 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            style="@style/VoteMinus"
            android:text="Minus" 
            android:id="@+id/tv_vote_minus"
            android:background="@drawable/change_tv_bg"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

change_tv_bg content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- focused and pressed-->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/green" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Have anybody encountered this problem ?

PS: sorry for my poor english, i'm french =)

Answer (score 0):

that whole layout with textViews is your listView item?

if its like that, i think that when you click on listItem, ListView sets all of yours textViews on state focused. Try to change colors in your xml file, and debug whats happening.

i've never experienced something like that :/

Comment: Yes The LinearLayout id ll_main is the ListView item. I have try different parameters as state_pressed, focused (in selector) ... and with multiple color but everytime i press on this global layout all child get the state pressed to true and focused to false (in selector file). And i have try to enable/disable android:descendantFocusability, and enable/disable android:duplicateParentState, to apply to my listview mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false); ListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); but don't function.
I become crazy :/